# return empty array in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a **number** collection and I need a query which returns values from an array.

```
 var Number = require('../models/number.js);
```

This is schema for `Number` model

```
{
    number: { type: Array },
    age: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Age',
        index: true
    },
    count: { type: Number },
    category: { type: String }
}
```

I have another `CategoryId` which retrieves well, for example `anotherCategoryId = 58454f5afd03356bfe726ade` and this `CategoryId` is also saved in my number array collection in the category.

I have queried the array number using this command below

```
var query = { 'number[category]' : anotherCategoryId };
var select = 'count';
Number.find(query, select, function(err, result){
    console.log(result)
}
```

But it returns empty arrays in console

```
  []
  []
  []
```

I have this JSON value in number array

```
    "number" : [ 
    {

        "category" : "5842b43780199d3ddb2d5f9f",
        "count" : 1,
        "age" : "5843b24dfce4224bf93091a0"
    }, 
    {

        "category" : "5842b43780199d3ddb2d5f9f",
        "count" : 1,
        "age" : "5843b275fce4224bf93091a1"
    }, 
    {        
        "category" : "5842b43780199d3ddb2d5f9f",
        "count" : 1,
        "age" : "5843b286fce4224bf93091a2"
    }, 
    {            
        "category" : "5841a9920c0f66650d592cc1",
        "count" : 1,
        "age" : "5843b2c0fce4224bf93091a3"
    }      
]
```

And I have another category ID collection

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5842b43780199d3ddb2d5f9f"),
  "categoryName" : "Science"
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5841a9920c0f66650d592cc1"),
  "categoryName" : "General awareness"
}
```

Then I need array query in number array so that I have to fetch related category id values from number array

Comment: try `var query = { category: anotherCategoryId };`

Comment: thanks but it generate same empty array

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a sample doc? It's not clear what's in `number`.

Comment: I have edited with JSON sample document

Comment: try `var query = { 'number.category' : anotherCategoryId };`

Comment: sir i have tried this one also but return empty array []